# getElementsByClassName onclick and return data

Tags: javascript, django

I have many these links in my template

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_to_cart" data-slug="{{ product.slug }}">Add</a>
```

And need click to the link and get certain `data-slug`. I try use `JS` and get all links so.

```
var add_to_cart = document.getElementsByClassName('add_to_cart');
```

After I try `for`

```
for(var i = 0; i < add_to_cart.length; i++) {
    product_slug = add_to_cart[i].getAttribute('data-slug')

    add_to_cart[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(product_slug)
    }
}
```

And after click always `console.log` have last `data-slug` latest link in my template. How to fix it and get the `data-slug` of the item I clicked on. Help me, please.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question at hand, but it's generally considered best practice to _not_ use anchor tags without an actual href attribute.  If you don't actually want to take the user somewhere, it's probably better to use a `<button>` and style it.

Comment: @ChrisHall exactly. Doing it that way is un-semantic.

Comment: @ChrisHall, okey, thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop does not work because the value of `product_slug` is set when the loop runs.
Because `product_slug` is a `var` you overwrite it each time the loop runs. And when the click listener is called `product_slug` will have the same value it had when the loop ran for the last time.

`var` creates a variable with function scope, it is defined in the scope of the function.

`let` or `const` creates a variable with block scope, it is defined in the scope of the block (inside the curly braces `{` `}`).

Read more about [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

So you want to use `let`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < add_to_cart.length; i++) {
    let product_slug = add_to_cart[i].getAttribute('data-slug')
    add_to_cart[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(product_slug)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the target of the click.  That's the `.target` attribute of the first argument to the event handler.

For example, the following code assigns an event handler to all the add_to_cart elements on the page and logs the slug to the console when they're clicked:

```
let add_to_cart_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.add_to_cart');

add_to_cart_buttons.forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.dataset.slug));
});
```

EDIT:  Apologies, I misread your second code block when I first wrote this.  Your use of `document.getElementsByClassName` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a variable that is written n times during a for loop, and n events that will display the value. That's why you have the same output each time.

What you can do is get the current target of your `onclick` event, and then display it's `data-slug` attribute

your for loop would look like this :

```
var add_to_cart = document.getElementsByClassName('add_to_cart');
for(var i = 0; i < add_to_cart.length; i++) {

    add_to_cart[i].onclick = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.getAttribute('data-slug'));
    }
}
```